# book recommendation - statistics in medicine

Tags: references, medicine

Could you recommend a book about the implementation of basic statistic concepts in medicine? In particular, I want to find a book that covers principal component analysis, correspondence analysis and clustering techniques, but in a medical context. Preferably, it should be a typical handbook with medical examples and very simple math, preferably using R for calculations (but it may be only handbook with theory).

Comment: PCA, correspondence analysis and clustering are *not* basic statistical concepts - they are quite advanced. Any book that has "theory" is going to have advanced math - statistical theory is mathematical.

Comment: @Peter Flom Yes, I understand that statistics is based on mathematics. I'm just looking for a book which explain this concepts using examples from medicine and is not focused on mathematics. I very like "Practice of Statistics in the Life Sciences" by Baldi, but this book (as many others which I found) covers only descriptive statistics and various types of regression. I haven't find book written similar to for example Baldi's handbook, but cover PCA, corespondence analysis etc.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was one that covered all three. You might not even find a book on each of them that uses examples from medicine.